# What unity dll version should I have?

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine, version

I'm using visual studio to code my Unity3D project.
Currently it is not accepting the following code:

```
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
```

When I look at the property inspector for the UnityEngine.dll it says that the "Runtime Version" is: v2.0.50727

My Unity Editor version is 5.1.1f1 Personal

- Is the dll version wrong?
- is it too old or too new?
- what is the most recent version?
- do I need to download something?
- where do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is a reference to **UnityEngine.UI.dll**.

Right click on your project, and select Add References. UnityEngine.UI.dll is usually under

```
Path_To_Unity_Installation/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/UnityEngine.UI.dll
```